# setfacl on directory seems not working for default permissions on sub directories

Tags: access-control-list

As root,
after creating a directory /Logs/case1, and setting the ACL to have default group "mygroup" permission as "rwx", any subdirectory created doesn't inherit those permissions

```
$ mkdir /Logs/case1    
$ setfacl -m g:mygroup:rwx /Logs/case1
```

here are the ACLs after setting them:

```
gc@logs:/Logs$ getfacl case1
# file: case1
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:mygroup:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Now as a regular user of the system, I'm supposed to create a sub directory under /Logs/case1

```
$ mkdir /Logs/case1/12345

gc@logs:/Logs/case1$ ls -lrt
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 gc mygroup 4096 Dec  1 00:16 12345

gc@logs:/Logs/case1$ getfacl 12345/
# file: 12345/
# owner: gc
# group: mygroup
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Why is this directory "/Logs/case1/12345" not inheriting the parent directory ACL for group "mygroup" - "rwx" ?

Here are the assigned groups to user "root" and "gc"

```
$ groups root
root : root

$ groups gc
gc : mygroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the file ACL for /Logs/case1, but not the default ACL. The file ACL isn't inherited, but the default ACL is. To add a default ACL:

```
setfacl -m g:mygroup:rwx,d:g:mygroup:rwx /Logs/case1
```

See [setfacl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl).

Comment: Did you mean setfacl -d -m g:mygroup:rwx /Logs/case1? Because above command is giving error 
setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 5

Comment: The syntax I showed works for me, but your OS (OSX?) may have a different syntax. `setfacl -d` also works, but requires you to use one command to set the permissions, and a second one to set the default permissions.

Comment: Yes, I had to separate it out.